# Trouble integrating in an efficient way

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble integrating this expression. It grew pretty complicated since it was originally a double integral. Not sure how to write in math on this site, but

$$I=\int\limits_{-2}^2 4(4-x^2)^{3/2}\ dx$$

I spent a long time doing different things, by parts etc. I also checked a the antiderivative table, but that gives me a different answer than the key. Further, I looked this up online and the calculators seem to have a weirdly long answer when my key says the integration is just:

$$\int\limits_{x=-2}^2 \left( (10x- x^3 )\sqrt{4- x^2} + 24 \sin^{-1} (x/2)\right) dx$$

How should I approach these types of problems?

Comment: Use MathJax to render the math Ethan.

Comment: I get $24 \pi$.

Comment: hint: the trigonometric substitution $x=2\cos(y)$ works since we are more or less looking for the area of a circle

Comment: Could you write the original double integral? It seems likely you missed some kind of symmetry argument since your integral is nonzero but the answer key integral evaluates to zero

Comment: Your key must have integrated by parts. But I don't think that's necessary here. The substitution $x=2\sin y$ should do it. You would now be integrating a constant multiple of $\cos^3y,$ which may be done by noting that $\cos 3y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y.$

Comment: @Allawonder that is impossible since both integrals evaluate to different things!

Comment: @NinadMunshi Then I'd say your answer key is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Use symmetry:

$$I = 2 \int\limits_{x=0}^2 4 (4- x^2)^{3/2}\ dx$$

Let $x = 2 \cos y$ and $dx = -2 \sin y\ dy$ and find $I = 24 \pi$.